# Checkbox mult-select array not will not push to $_POST while inside a for loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html, post

long post so this is my disclaimer.

I'm working on a function that builds a table from a MYSQL database and displays it in a webpage (using localhost XAMP). That part was easy, figured out that no problem. However, I attempted to make another column for checkboxes to allow me to check off the entries I would like to delete, then click the delete button to delete all those selected. Here is the full function:

```
<?php // functions.php
$conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) die ($conn->$connect_error);

function buildTable($query) {
global $conn;  // need clarification why this works
$result = $conn->query($query);
if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);

$rows = $result->num_rows;

echo "<table> <tr> <th>Delete</th> <th>stockID</th> <th>cardID</th> 
<th>categoryID</th> <th>condID</th> <th>Potential Value</th> </tr> ";

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j) {
    $result->data_seek($j);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

This bit of the code is my problem; when I print_r($_POST) on the action page 'inventory.php' the $_POST array doesn't show stockID to exist.

```
  echo "<tr> <td> <form method='post' action='inventory.php'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='stockID[]' value='$rows[0]'> 
  </form></td>";

    for ($l = 0 ; $l < 5 ; ++$l) echo "<td>$row[$l]</td>";

    echo "</tr>";

};
```

End possible problem bit, continue rest of code:

```
echo <<<_END
?>
</table> <a href='card input.php'> Record inventory </a> 
<form method='post' action='inventory.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='delete' value='true'>
<input type='submit' value='Delete Record(s)'>
</form>
_END;
};
```

I then use this IF statement on the action page to determine what is to be deleted:

```
<?php //inventory.php <-- NOTICE NEW FILE
if ( isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['stockID']) ) {
  $stockID = $_POST['stockID'];
  foreach ($stockID as $value) {
    $query = 'DELETE FROM `itemized inventory` 
                    WHERE stockID="$value" ';
    queryMysql($query);
  };
};
```

Possible issues i've visited:

1.) **stockID is used on another file in the same directory and is conflicting.** 
I don't think two identical associative array keys will conflict if they're on two different files that are not connected by a 'require' or 'include' call. I'm newb so I could be wrong. Ive alse tried different ID's, without it fixing the issue.

2.) **My IF statement to call the DELETE command into SQL is incorrect.**
This could still be true, but I don't think I can even say that for sure because I would be getting an error message due to my queryMysql($query) function.

```
<?php //function.php
function queryMysql($query) {
global $conn;
$result = $conn->query($query);
if (!$result) echo "Database action failed: $query" . "<br>" .
    $conn->error . "<br><br>"; 
};
?>
```

Because I'm not a.) receiving an error and b.) not deleting anything from the database, it leads me to conclude that the `<input type='checkbox' name='stockID[]' value='$row[0]'>` from the 'functions.php page' is not being pushed to the $_POST array on the action page 'inventory.php' (further confirmed by using print_r($_POST) on the 'inventory.php' page). Because isset($_POST['stockID']) is then false, the IF statement to determine what is to be deleted is not even being called because its condition is false. Therefore, the query isn't even being submitted, and so I cannot prove this to be the problem.

3.)**For loops and heredocs are not friends.** Maybe? At this point i'm just guessing.... Maybe its for loops and `<input>` statements that aren't friends?

Thats about all I can think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Newb programmer and poster here on stack so plz go easy. Roughness is okay as along as we snuggle afterwards.

thanks!

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Few of us have the time or inclination to read all the way through this kind of ramble. Likely as not you are going to get answers based on the first trivial thing people see as wrong in your code, which will have little or nothing to do with what you are actually asking

Comment: Newb poster and programmer here as said at the end of my essay :). Still learning what information is necessary and not. Thanks for the link I will read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This last form with the Delete button has no fields named "stockID[]". These fields belong to other forms, so they are not sent with this form.

You can wrap the whole table with checkboxes into one form

```
<form method='post' action='inventory.php'>
  <table> <tr> <th>Delete</th> <th>stockID</th> <th>cardID</th>
  <th>categoryID</th> <th>condID</th> <th>Potential Value</th> </tr>
  <?php
  for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j) {
    $result->data_seek($j);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    echo "<tr> <td><input type='checkbox' name='stockID[]' value='$rows[0]'></td>";
    for ($l = 0 ; $l < 5 ; ++$l) echo "<td>$row[$l]</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  };
  </table>
  <input type='hidden' name='delete' value='true'>
  <input type='submit' value='Delete Record(s)'>
</form>
```

Or call javascript function before sending the last form, collect values of all checked checkboxes, and pass this into the sent data.

Comment: fixed, thank you :). Having two seperate forms was indeed the issue.